# Bootstrap carousel event isn't work in Firefox browser

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to customize the bootstrap carousel to make it a simple content slider. I saw two events in bootstrap docs and using animate.css for animation, chrome even Internet explorer showing the animation perfectly. but in firefox animation working just for first time.

here is the code I used to set the animation

```
$('#home-slider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
$('#home-slider .slideInLeftTrigger').removeClass('slideInLeft');
$('#home-slider .fadeInRightBigTrigger').removeClass('fadeInRightBig');

$('#home-slider .slideInLeftTrigger').addClass('slideInLeft');
$('#home-slider .fadeInRightBigTrigger').addClass('fadeInRightBig');

console.log('next');
})
```

Mysterious thing is console log is printing perfectly but the **addClass** and **removeClass** isn't working.

Is there any way to show the animation in all browser?

**I'm new here, pardon me for any mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem now its working on firefox,

I was going to delete this topic but may be its better to keep the solution here for future referance.

I used two bootstrap carousel events, one for removing animation class and one to adding,

```
$('#home-slider').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  $('#home-slider .slideInLeftTrigger').removeClass('slideInLeft');
  $('#home-slider .fadeInRightBigTrigger').removeClass('fadeInRightBig');
})

$('#home-slider').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  $('#home-slider .slideInLeftTrigger').addClass('slideInLeft');
  $('#home-slider .fadeInRightBigTrigger').addClass('fadeInRightBig');

})
```

Thanks